# Find id of element where display property is block

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to return the id of an element which display property attribute is 'block'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("*"); // use an appropriate filter
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList, 0);
var elements = array.filter(function (element) { return window.getComputedStyle(element).display === "block"; });
var ids =  elements.map(function (element) { return element.id; });
```

The solution presented above searches the page for elements and then keeps only the ones which have a computed display of block. Works even if the style is not inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

Javascript

```
 var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
 for (var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    display = divs[i].style.display;    
    if(display == 'block' ){
         alert(divs[i].getAttribute('id'));
    }
}
```

Html

```
<div id="1" style="display:block;">this is div 1</div>    
<div id="2" style="display:block;">this is div 2</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none;">this is div 3</div>
```

Please refer to the fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/UAYWD/21/"

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(divs[i].style.display == 'block'){
        alert(divs[i].id);
    }
}
```

.

```
<div id="div1" style="display:block;">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:block;">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">Div 3</div>
```

Output:

div1

div2

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mhqwaxpw/

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("div").each(function(){
       if($(this).css("display")=="block"){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
       }
    });
```